# surprising linq except behavior

Tags: c#, linq

I was really surprised by the following linq except behavior, can anybody explain why? I've listed my understands/assumptions of how linq works. At least one of them is wrong.

1. The first line defines list1 that would yields Obj('a') and Obj('b') when evaluated.
2. The second line defines list2 that yields Obj('b') which should be the same object(reference equal) that yielded from list1.
3. The third line defines list3 that yields Obj('a'), which should be the same(reference equal) object yielded from list1.

```
public class Obj {
    public string Name;
    public Obj(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = "a,b"
            .Split(',')
            .Select(x => new Obj(x));
        var list2 = list1.Where(x => x.Name == "b");
        var list3 = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
    }
}
```

But apparently, this is not the case. When inspected in debugger, list3 contains {Obj('a'), Obj('b')}, and those objects are not the references equals of what list1 contains. And Obj constructor are called 4 times.

Shouldn't linq Where and Excet methods just copy object references from one IEnumerable to another IEnumerable? Who is it creating object copies?

Comment: This behaviour seems correct to me. Remember that LINQ is effectively a view, and doesn't materialise anything until you ask it to.

Comment: @John this is what's confusing me. If they are just views, the list1, ilst2, and list3 should be just different views into the same 2 objects. But when debugged, in total 4 objects are created.

Comment: They are both views into the array produced by `"a,b".Split(',')`, not views of `list1`.

Comment: @John, Thanks. I think I get what you mean.

Comment: I was going to incorporate this into an answer, but Jon beat me to the punch. Here's an [example](https://rextester.com/RGWOK35387) - It demonstrates that nothing is actually evaluated until you materialise the result. And [another example](https://rextester.com/ECSV42301) where we materialise `list1` before doing anything else.

Comment: @John Thank you both. This is not the first time he had helped me. And you have corrected one of the misunderstandings that I deeply believed that I understood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your lists aren't really lists - they're lazily evaluated sequences. When this code excutes:

```cs
var list1 = "a,b"
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => new Obj(x));
```

... the `Split` is called immediately, and then `Where` is called to set up a lazily-evaluated sequence over that array. If you don't iterate over `list1` at all, no instances of `Obj` will be created. If you iterate over `list1` multiple times, you'll get new objects each time.

All you need to do to get your code to work is *materialize* the query by converting to a list (or an array would work too):

```cs
var list1 = "a,b"
    .Split(',')
    .Select(x => new Obj(x))
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, you could override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in `Obj`, so that `Except` would consider different-but-equal objects appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you use foreach , It Invoke `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` And It will new Object

```
public class Obj
    {
        public string Name;
        public Obj(string name)
        {
            Debug.LogFormat("HI");
            this.Name = name;
        }
    }
        var list1 = "a,b"
               .Split(',')
               .Select(x => new Obj(x));
        foreach (var v in list1)
        { }
```

Output: HI HI

And If you run two foreach , It will Inovke Double `IEnumerator.MoveNext()`

```
foreach (var v in list1)
            { }
foreach (var v in list1)
            { }
```

Output: HI HI HI HI

So it same with use Except & toList , It also like foreach list1

```
var list2 = list1.Where(x => x.Name == "b");
var list3 = list1.Except(list2);// output HI HI
list3.ToList();// output HIHI
```